# Can't run python script from R in aws and Rstudio

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services

I am trying to call python script to call parallel api calls which is wrapped in function. However, I am not able to execute python script from Rstudio in local computer or R in aws.

Following is my code for python.

```
import sys
from numpy.random import randint


if len(sys.argv)==5:
    ci = int(sys.argv[1])
    cd  = bool(sys.argv[2])
    db = str(sys.argv[3])
    fc = bool(sys.argv[4])
else:
    ci = 296
    cd  = True
    db = "snap_uat"
    fc = False

if cd & fc:
    print db
    randit(ci)
```

R code:

```
cd <- function(ci, cd, db, fc){

     ServiceLog <-  system(
      paste(
            "ipython", "callpython.py",
            ci,
            cd, db,
            fp, sep = " ")
      , intern = TRUE
  )



)
```

error is as follows:

> sh: 1: ipython: not found

It is my assumption that it is not calling python from anaconda but inbuilt python. which don't have ipython

Comment: Are you sure you have iPython installed on EC2 instance and your local computer?

Comment: yes, I have install anaconda python2.7 on aws.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct call from np.random import randint as I am getting error when I am trying to run that python command

Comment: Sorry, I used np rather than numpy. I have updated code. Thanks

Comment: So did it worked? Or still the same error?

Comment: Same error, it is saying ipython not found.it will run on local r. but not in Rstudio or R in AWS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113438/discussion-between-error2007s-and-kppatel-patel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is right, AWS EC2 was calling default python, not calling anaconda python. So I had to install module in default python.

installing module in default is fist install apt-get install

```
sudo apt-get install pip
```

then install all modules using sudo pip install.